# Converting list into dataframe and reshaping the dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an various image with pixel data 32x32x3 in list form. 
For example.

```
head(images.rgb1[1])
```

```
[[1]]
     x    y   z
1    1    2   3
2    4    5   6
```

I am trying to convert this image.rgb[1] list into dataframe like 
1 2 3 4 5 6 ......

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split up this task in two steps:

1: Iterate over list of images and extract all pixel colours into one vector:

```
pixel_vec = lapply(images.rgb1, function(x) c(t(x)))
```

2: Bind all pixel vectors together to build you dataframe

```
data.frame(do.call(rbind, pixel_vec))
```

However, I'm not sure if this is the better format for your next tasks?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code should be `as.data.frame(matrix(t(as.matrix(df)),nrow = 1))`, where `df` is the data frame you showed as an example

```
df <- structure(list(r = c(59L, 43L, 50L, 68L, 98L, 119L, 139L, 145L
), g = c(62L, 46L, 48L, 54L, 73L, 91L, 107L, 110L), b = c(63L, 
45L, 43L, 42L, 52L, 63L, 75L, 80L)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```